# Is it appropriate to ask how-would-you-explain-to-a-beginner -style questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have a couple friends that I involve as sounding boards for ideas. Sometimes I have a hard time translating some intermediate-to-advanced concepts to them, and I wonder if I can ask math.stackexchange for their wisdom on how best to approach certain topics to those unfamiliar.

> Would this style of question be appropriate to ask of Math.SE?

Comment: In case you do not know about it there is also [matheducators.se] which is dedicated to questions on how to teach mathematics.

Comment: @quid Awesome! Thank you. I wasn't aware of that.